# How do I create a polygon based on a single point?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, polygon-creation, xy

I have been given a large spreadsheet of sample data where each point coordinate represents the end of the sampling extent. I am tasked to represent these points as a sampling extent of 100' x 8' with the point being the end. The spreadsheet has from and to directions (EW - from East to West) so that I have the direction that the polygon should be oriented.

I have over a thousand records to create polygons for so manual digitizing is not really an option for the timeline given.

Does anyone know of any tools that can create a polygon based on a point location and extent indicators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

was able to figure this one out with the help of a coworker, so in case anyone is interested here was the workflow:

1. Select a set of points that have the same orientation (eg EW)
2. Copy / Paste points and then Move 100feet in the direction of the orientation (ex direction of EW would mean I move the point E or -100feet)
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 for remaining orientations
4. Use point to line tool and use a unique field ID (in this case I had a tagID that identified each point set) in the Line_field.
5. Once the lines are created for each set of points use the Buffer tool to create a 8' buffer with flat ends.

This will give the 100' x 8' rectangle. My model includes a few other steps for generating additional data, but those are the basic steps for creating a polygon with only one point input.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about the solution in ModelBuilder but there are many ways to do that in Python.

First, you need to read the records using one of the [excel libraries](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966) or export it to text and loop over the text file.
Then create geometries - quadrangles based on your requirements and [write them into a feature class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Writing_geometries/002z0000001v000000/)

You can also look at [Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) library for creating polygons and [ogr/gdal](http://www.gdal.org/) for persisting the data.